# Python скрипт цен крипты для импорта в Notion таблицу

Tags: python, api, криптография

Мой запрос будет довольно странным, ввиду того что я не программист. Мне нужно вытягивать данные с любого открытого API, которое предоставляет цены по криптовалютам и затягивать их в Notion в таблицу.

Я нашел скрипт, который это делает, с горем пополам его немного изменил с помощью ChatGPT и добавил комментариев с его же помощью.

```
import requests

# ключ API для Notion
secret = "API key"

# ID базы данных в Notion
wallet_db_id = "my db id"

# базовые URL для работы с базой данных и страницами в Notion, а также URL для получения котировок криптовалют
base_db_url = "https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/"
base_pg_url = "https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/"
base_crypto_url = "https://api.coinlore.net/api/tickers/?start=0&limit=100"

# заголовок для запросов к API Notion
header = {"Authorization": secret, "Notion-Version": "2021-05-13", "Content-Type": "application/json"}

# получение данных из базы данных в Notion
data = {}
response = requests.post(base_db_url + wallet_db_id + "/query", headers=header, data=data)

# обработка данных для каждой страницы в базе данных
for page in response.json()["results"]:
    page_id = page["id"]
    props = page['properties']

    asset_code = props['Symbol']['rich_text'][0]['plain_text']

    # получение котировок криптовалют
    request_by_code = requests.get(base_crypto_url).json()['data']
    
    # поиск котировки по коду актива
    coin = next((item for item in request_by_code if item["symbol"] == asset_code), None)
            
    # формирование данных для отправки на страницу в Notion
    if(request_by_code != []):
        price = coin['price_usd']
        price_btc = coin['price_btc'] 
        pcent_24h = coin['percent_change_24h']
        pcent_7days = coin['percent_change_7d']
        coin_url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/" + coin['nameid']

        data_price = '{"properties":   \
                        {"Price, USD": { "number":' + str(price) + '},\
                        "Price, BTC": { "number":' + str(price_btc) + '}, \
                        "24h %": { "number":' + str(pcent_24h) + '}, \
                        "7d %": { "number":' + str(pcent_7days) + '}, \
                        "URL": { "url":"' + coin_url + '"}}}'

        # отправка данных на страницу в Notion
        send_price = requests.patch(base_pg_url + page_id, headers=header, data=data_price)
```

Но в API coinlore недостаточно данных, которые мне нужны, а именно не предоставляются данные о цене за 30 и 90 дней. Я пытался заменить на API livecoinwatch, а так же coinstats, но у меня ничего не вышло из-за отсутствия знаний в этой области.

Так же в планах было добавить сюда возможность вытягивать по API Binance информацию о своих активах, но далее так и не продвинулся.

Что можете порекомендовать, кроме изучения?

Но в API coinlore недостаточно данных, которые мне нужны, а именно не предоставляются данные о цене за 30 и 90 дней. Я пытался заменить на API livecoinwatch, а так же coinstats, но у меня ничего не вышло из-за отсутствия знаний в этой области.

Так же в планах было добавить сюда возможность вытягивать по API Binance информацию о своих активах, но далее так и не продвинулся.

Что можете порекомендовать, кроме изучения?

Answer (score 0):

> Мне нужно вытягивать данные с любого открытого API, которое предоставляет цены по криптовалютам.>

> Но в API coinlore недостаточно данных, которые мне нужны, а именно не предоставляются данные о цене за 30 и 90 дней.>

> Что можете порекомендовать, кроме изучения?

Вместо того, что бы мучатся с API, вы могли бы брать информацию о ценах по криптовалютам из публичных сайтов, использую парсер python(BeautifulSoup и request)